# SVG viewBox Attribute Makes D3Js Line chart disappear

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am trying to make my d3.js scatter plot/line graph visualization responsive and have followed information that has mentioned the only way to scale an svg with your window is by using the `viewBox` attribute, but it appears when I switch out the with and height attributes in my svg to the viewBox attribute the chart disappears without any error. Is there something that I am doing wrong with applying this attribute to my chart?

Attribute switched from:

```
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
```

To this:

```
.attr( 'preserveAspectRatio',"xMinYMin meet")
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + margin.left + margin.right + " " + height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
```

**Here is the visualization with the new change:**

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>

    var data = [
        { "x": "2020-04-26", "y": 461.0, "label": "7:41" },
        { "x": "2020-04-27", "y": 421.0, "label": "7:01" },
        { "x": "2020-04-28", "y": 519.0, "label": "8:39" },
        { "x": "2020-04-29", "y": 502.0, "label": "8:22" },
        { "x": "2020-04-30", "y": 511.0, "label": "8:31" },
        { "x": "2020-05-01", "y": 513.0, "label": "8:33" },
        { "x": "2020-05-02", "y": 496.0, "label": "8:16" },
        { "x": "2020-05-03", "y": 480.0, "label": "8:00" },
        { "x": "2020-05-04", "y": 364.0, "label": "6:04" },
        { "x": "2020-05-05", "y": 498.0, "label": "8:18" },
        { "x": "2020-05-06", "y": 467.0, "label": "7:47" },
        { "x": "2020-05-07", "y": 477.0, "label": "7:57" },
        { "x": "2020-05-08", "y": 431.0, "label": "7:11" },
        { "x": "2020-05-09", "y": 419.0, "label": "6:59" },
        { "x": "2020-05-10", "y": 471.0, "label": "7:51" },
        { "x": "2020-05-11", "y": 391.0, "label": "6:31" },
        { "x": "2020-05-12", "y": 481.0, "label": "8:01" },
        { "x": "2020-05-13", "y": 494.0, "label": "8:14" },
        { "x": "2020-05-14", "y": 506.0, "label": "8:26" },
        { "x": "2020-05-15", "y": 464.0, "label": "7:44" },
        { "x": "2020-05-16", "y": 474.0, "label": "7:54" },
        { "x": "2020-05-17", "y": 383.0, "label": "6:23" },
        { "x": "2020-05-18", "y": 385.0, "label": "6:25" },
        { "x": "2020-05-19", "y": 470.0, "label": "7:50" },
        { "x": "2020-05-20", "y": 465.0, "label": "7:45" },
        { "x": "2020-05-21", "y": 574.0, "label": "9:34" },
        { "x": "2020-05-22", "y": 473.0, "label": "7:53" },
        { "x": "2020-05-23", "y": 431.0, "label": "7:11" },
        { "x": "2020-05-24", "y": 497.0, "label": "8:17" },
        { "x": "2020-05-26", "y": 482.0, "label": "8:02" },
        { "x": "2020-05-27", "y": 492.0, "label": "8:12" },
        { "x": "2020-05-28", "y": 494.0, "label": "8:14" },
        { "x": "2020-05-29", "y": 469.0, "label": "7:49" },
        { "x": "2020-05-30", "y": 395.0, "label": "6:35" },
        { "x": "2020-05-31", "y": 427.0, "label": "7:07" },
        { "x": "2020-06-01", "y": 346.0, "label": "5:46" },
        { "x": "2020-06-02", "y": 416.0, "label": "6:56" },
        { "x": "2020-06-03", "y": 461.0, "label": "7:41" },
        { "x": "2020-06-04", "y": 486.0, "label": "8:06" },
        { "x": "2020-06-05", "y": 451.0, "label": "7:31" },
        { "x": "2020-06-06", "y": 533.0, "label": "8:53" },
        { "x": "2020-06-08", "y": 462.0, "label": "7:42" },
        { "x": "2020-06-09", "y": 461.0, "label": "7:41" }
    ]
    
    // D3 date parser
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        var parser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")
        data[i].date = parser(data[i].x);
    }

    console.log(data)
    var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60  }
    var width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    // Define the div for the tooltip
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
        .attr("class", "tooltip")               
        .style("opacity", 0);

    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
        .append("svg")
            // .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            // .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr( 'preserveAspectRatio',"xMinYMin meet")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + margin.left + margin.right + " " + height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); // translate(margin left, margin top)

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.date }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.date })])
        .range([0, width]);
    
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // text label for the x axis
    svg.append("text")             
        .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + (height + margin.top + 20) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Date");

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return +d.y })])
        .range([height, 0]);
    
    svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // text label for the y axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Time Asleep (Minutes)");

    // Add line path
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.y) })
        );

    // Add the scatterplot (data points)
    svg.selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3)
        .attr("cx", function(d){ return x(d.date) })
        .attr("cy", function(d){ return y(d.y) })
    

</script>
```

**Here is the chart with the height and width attribute:**

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>

    var data = [
        { "x": "2020-04-26", "y": 461.0, "label": "7:41" },
        { "x": "2020-04-27", "y": 421.0, "label": "7:01" },
        { "x": "2020-04-28", "y": 519.0, "label": "8:39" },
        { "x": "2020-04-29", "y": 502.0, "label": "8:22" },
        { "x": "2020-04-30", "y": 511.0, "label": "8:31" },
        { "x": "2020-05-01", "y": 513.0, "label": "8:33" },
        { "x": "2020-05-02", "y": 496.0, "label": "8:16" },
        { "x": "2020-05-03", "y": 480.0, "label": "8:00" },
        { "x": "2020-05-04", "y": 364.0, "label": "6:04" },
        { "x": "2020-05-05", "y": 498.0, "label": "8:18" },
        { "x": "2020-05-06", "y": 467.0, "label": "7:47" },
        { "x": "2020-05-07", "y": 477.0, "label": "7:57" },
        { "x": "2020-05-08", "y": 431.0, "label": "7:11" },
        { "x": "2020-05-09", "y": 419.0, "label": "6:59" },
        { "x": "2020-05-10", "y": 471.0, "label": "7:51" },
        { "x": "2020-05-11", "y": 391.0, "label": "6:31" },
        { "x": "2020-05-12", "y": 481.0, "label": "8:01" },
        { "x": "2020-05-13", "y": 494.0, "label": "8:14" },
        { "x": "2020-05-14", "y": 506.0, "label": "8:26" },
        { "x": "2020-05-15", "y": 464.0, "label": "7:44" },
        { "x": "2020-05-16", "y": 474.0, "label": "7:54" },
        { "x": "2020-05-17", "y": 383.0, "label": "6:23" },
        { "x": "2020-05-18", "y": 385.0, "label": "6:25" },
        { "x": "2020-05-19", "y": 470.0, "label": "7:50" },
        { "x": "2020-05-20", "y": 465.0, "label": "7:45" },
        { "x": "2020-05-21", "y": 574.0, "label": "9:34" },
        { "x": "2020-05-22", "y": 473.0, "label": "7:53" },
        { "x": "2020-05-23", "y": 431.0, "label": "7:11" },
        { "x": "2020-05-24", "y": 497.0, "label": "8:17" },
        { "x": "2020-05-26", "y": 482.0, "label": "8:02" },
        { "x": "2020-05-27", "y": 492.0, "label": "8:12" },
        { "x": "2020-05-28", "y": 494.0, "label": "8:14" },
        { "x": "2020-05-29", "y": 469.0, "label": "7:49" },
        { "x": "2020-05-30", "y": 395.0, "label": "6:35" },
        { "x": "2020-05-31", "y": 427.0, "label": "7:07" },
        { "x": "2020-06-01", "y": 346.0, "label": "5:46" },
        { "x": "2020-06-02", "y": 416.0, "label": "6:56" },
        { "x": "2020-06-03", "y": 461.0, "label": "7:41" },
        { "x": "2020-06-04", "y": 486.0, "label": "8:06" },
        { "x": "2020-06-05", "y": 451.0, "label": "7:31" },
        { "x": "2020-06-06", "y": 533.0, "label": "8:53" },
        { "x": "2020-06-08", "y": 462.0, "label": "7:42" },
        { "x": "2020-06-09", "y": 461.0, "label": "7:41" }
    ]
    
    // D3 date parser
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        var parser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")
        data[i].date = parser(data[i].x);
    }

    console.log(data)
    var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60  }
    var width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    // Define the div for the tooltip
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
        .attr("class", "tooltip")               
        .style("opacity", 0);

    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            // .attr( 'preserveAspectRatio',"xMinYMin meet")
            // .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + margin.left + margin.right + " " + height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); // translate(margin left, margin top)

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.date }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.date })])
        .range([0, width]);
    
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // text label for the x axis
    svg.append("text")             
        .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + (height + margin.top + 20) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Date");

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return +d.y })])
        .range([height, 0]);
    
    svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // text label for the y axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Time Asleep (Minutes)");

    // Add line path
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.y) })
        );

    // Add the scatterplot (data points)
    svg.selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3)
        .attr("cx", function(d){ return x(d.date) })
        .attr("cy", function(d){ return y(d.y) })
    

</script>
```

Comment: the viewBox is enormous because you're adding the values as strings rather than doing maths. You need  extra brackets to force the values to be mathematically added before string conversion. Use your browser's javascript debugger to check what's happening.

Comment: Are you using a parent div to wrap around the svg? If so, I don't think you need to use attribute preserveAspectRatio. I've never used it because it sometimes force part of the graph out of the viewbox. Try removing it and just  use viewBox to control the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not adding, it's coercing the numbers to strings then concatenating:

`.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + margin.left + margin.right + " " + height + margin.top + margin.bottom)`

This will add, then coerce and concatenate:

`.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + (width + margin.left + margin.right) + " " + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))`

Comment: Makes complete sense. Thank you for the help!